# Помещение структур в QVector

Tags: c++, qt

Как происходит помещение структур в вектор? Допустим я задал некую структуру

```
struct patch
{
    quint32 address;
    quint32 size;
    unsigned char* _p_patch;
};
```

потом переменную `patch p`, могу ли я заполнять эту переменную различными данными и добавлять в вектор, или нужно каждый раз создавать ее через нью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `std::vector` это будет так:

```
 patch p;
 p.address = 1;
 p.size = 1;
 p._p_patch = "ABC";

 std::vector<patch> vPatch;
 vPatch.push_back(p);
```

В Qt также.

и не надо ничего выделять через `new`. Не знаю правда что с `patch::_p_patch`, если под это поле выделяется память то нужно ее сначала удалить через `delete`,  а потом из вектора.

**UPD**

В этом случае при добавлении в вектор произошло копирование объекта `p`. Теперь он лежит в двух местах: в векторе и в переменной `p`. Можно конечно сделать так чтобы вектор содержал указатель на `patch`:

```
 patch* p = new patch;
 p->address = 1;
 p->size = 1;
 p->_p_patch = "ABC";

 std::vector<patch*> vPatch;
 vPatch.push_back(p);
 // работаем с вектором
 ...
 //чистим
for(size_t i = 0; i < vPatch.size(); i++)
     delete vPatch[i];
```

В этом случае нужно освобождать память, иначе будет утечка.

Comment: то есть при добавлении элемента вектора происходит копирование?

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Не забудьте про конструктор копирования для своей структуры, если он необходим, ну а если используете новый с++, то неплохо и конструктор перемещения сделать.

Comment: что есть конструктор копирования??

Comment: У вас в структуре  есть указатель. При копировании этой структуры будет скопирован и указатель. То есть получится два объекта у который есть поле указывающих на одну и туже область памяти. Что бы эту ситуацию проконтролировать можно определить конструктор в этой структуре который принимает ссылку на объект этой структуры, и в нем обработать эту ситуацию.

Comment: @DowJhob, когда вы пишете вот так  `vPatch.push_back(p);`, то в вектор попадает копия р, которая создается вызовом конструктора копирования. А поскольку у вас в структуре указатели, то при создании копии надо руками выделить память и скопировать туда данные, иначе вы получите два указателя в разных структурах, но указывающих на одну область памяти.

Comment: Не, контролем ссылок занимаюсь самостоятельно, то есть сначала создаю через нью массив char сохраняю ссылку на него в структуре и потом структуру уже сохраняю в векторе. Структура же нужна для сохранения размера и адреса.

Comment: >>В этом случае нужно освобождать память, иначе будет утечка.<< Или использовать умный указатель.